# java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider 'wsjar' not installed

Tags: java, websphere

I am getting this exception report due to a file path not being found correctly.

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "wsjar" not installed
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:158)
```

I am running Websphere v8.5.5.0.

I am calling the Path Like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = ...
URI uri = clazz.getResource("/project.properties").toURI();
Path propertyFilePath = Paths.get(uri); //error here.
```

Can someone please explain what the wsjar file name means? and what i can do to get around this error?

P.S. i will get the actual uri.toString here once i run it with a System.out.println statement.

**UPDATE:** the actual URI string is as follows:

```
wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_1/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/AUSSYDCVTLJ007Node02Cell/myapp.ear/lib/core.jar!/project.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

`wsjar` is the websphere specific URL protocol for an entry in a jar file.

And one solution that can be done from your code can be to reconstruct the URL like something below:

```
 if (uri.getProtocol().startsWith("wsjar")) 
     URL updatedURL = new URL("jar", uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), uri.getPath());
```

Similar issue discussed here.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XW-669

Comment: There is no `.getProtocol()` method for URI. also when i output the state of those three uri functions in the new URL, i get `uri.getHost() == null, uri.getPort() == -1 and uri.getPath() == null`.

Comment: it should be URL. URL url = clazz.getResource("/project.properties");  and from this you should be able to use protocol and the other methods.